# Mariadb clustering Index design question

Tags: optimization, mariadb, clustered-index, auto-increment

Here are the columns of concern for a table describing tasks:

- Org_ID
- Task_ID
- Task_property_columns

The only requirement for `Task_ID` is that it is unique per every `Org_ID`, however I would prefer not handle that programatically and that it be **auto incremented**.

The requirement for the `Org_ID` is that I would like to run metrics and analytics using sort operations with the table organised by `Org_ID` and ported nationally some of the task properties. The table being clustered on `Task_ID` would be useless,  but would be very beneficial to generate on `Org_ID`.

From reviewing the documentation, it seems that clustering is picked for you in MariaDB where it will use the **primary key**, a **unique non-nullable index**, or a **background auto generated index** in that order.

I am pretty  new to MariaDB and was hoping for some help in picking the right solution. From what I understand I can't find a good way to auto increment and cluster how I want it to as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, to clarify: "cluster" in this Question refers to the "clustering" of the `PRIMARY KEY` with the data, not the "clustering of servers".

You have provided the 3 choices *that InnoDB makes* to picks the clustered PK.  Let me rephrase it from a user point of view.

1. *If* you have a column, or combination of columns, (all non-`NULL`) that are inherently `UNIQUE`, then use it as the PK.  This is a "natural" PK.
2. If choice 1 is not available, use an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
3. Though available, do not use the third choice of an auto-generated hidden PK.  Some day, you will need to uniquely identify rows, perhaps for maintenance.

Unlike some other vendors, there is no `ROWNUM`, nor is there a non-clustered PK.  The lack of those is *not* important.

Secondary keys let you get at the data in other ways.  A secondary key contains a copy of the PK so that it can get to the data.  Both PK and secondary keys are organized as BTrees.  BTree is the best all-around indexing method; the lack of Hash, etc, is *not* important.

A natural PK lets you do a range scan over the PK column very efficiently.

If find that two-thirds of tables have a "natural" PK; only one-third need an auto_increment instead.

Back to your 'task'.  It sounds like you want

```
PRIMARY KEY(org_id, task_id)
```

but would like `task_id` to be automatically generated.  This is possible by saying

```
task_id, INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
```

but there will be gaps -- since the auto_inc is table-wide, not specific to a given `org_id`.  If you can live with the gaps, then that is your answer.

This was a feature that existed in ENGINE=MyISAM.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk) for a simulation of it using InnoDB.

You mentioned "ported nationally".  Are you trying to create unique ids that are locally, not centrally, generated?  See UUID and [*its evils*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid).

If you are summarizing large quantities of data, then build and maintain [*Summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

If you want to discuss further, please provide prototypes of schema and queries.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed feedback! I thought that auto increment was only available for the "Left" most column of the primary key? I'll have to test that out.  Also,  I found this example while walking though the Mariadb tutorials: "ALTER TABLE client_addresses ORDER BY city, name;" Does this essentially change what the table is clustered on?

Comment: @Scotty - That `ALTER` only works for MyISAM.  With InnoDB, the data is always in `PRIMARY KEY` order.

Comment: @Scotty - With MyISAM, the auto_inc can be second.  With other engines, it must be first (in at least one index).  Although MyISAM possibly fixes one of your questions, I do not recommend it for production use.